# How to evaluate this trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

I am new to trigonometry, and know some basic identities such as **double angle formulae**, and **transformation of sum into product**, I need to simplify:

$$ 3\left[ \sin^4\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\alpha \right) + \sin^4(3\pi + \alpha) \ \right] - 2 \  \left[\sin^6\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha \right) + \sin^6(5\pi + \alpha ) \ \right] $$

How to simplify?

Okay, I simplified it as $$ 3 [ -\cos^4\alpha + \sin^4\alpha ] - 2 $$ how to proceed further?

Comment: First, you should simplify the parts inside the brackets so that only $\alpha$ remains in each bracket. To do this, use summation formulas, for example $\sin(\frac \pi 2 + \alpha)$ can be simplified to $\cos \alpha$.

Comment: start by $\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$

Comment: Make the additions part of the QUESTION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not make out how you arrived at that step.

I'm posting here my answer.
\begin{align*}
3[\sin^4(\frac{3\pi}{2}-a)+\sin^4(3\pi+a)]-2[\sin^6(\frac{\pi}{2}+a)+\sin^6(5\pi+a)]\\ = 3[\cos^4(a)+\sin^4(a)]-2[\cos^6(a)+\sin^6(a)]\\
= 3[\cos^4(a)+\sin^4(a)]-2[(\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a))(\cos^4(a)-\sin^2(a)\cos^2(a)+\sin^4(a))]\\
=3[\cos^4 a+ \sin^4 a]-2[\cos^4 a-\sin^2 a \cos^2 a +\sin^4 a]\\
= \cos^4 a + \sin^4 a +2 \sin^2 a \cos^2 a\\
= (\cos^2 a+\sin^2 a)^2\\
=1
\end{align*}